# Regex to find a sub-string that starts and ends with particular word

Tags: php, regex

I have following string multiple time in my paragraph which I want to show on my page

`START_num_360_250_END`

Here `num` can be any number of any digit, this string can be anywhere in the paragraph and any number of times. And `num` can be repeated in that string (that is duplicate strings). I want these strings in the para one at a time.

I am doing following.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$file_count;$i++){
    preg_match( '/START_'.$i.'(.*)_END/', $p_info['blog_content'], $match);
    print_r($match);
}
```

eg. if I have that string two times in my paragraph as follows
`START_1_360_250_END` `START_2_360_250_END`

I should get `START_1_360_250_END` for 1st iteration in `for loop` (as `num` here is 1), even if that string appears any number of times I should get it only once. And `START_2_360_250_END` for second iteration as `num` here is `2`.

but this is what I get.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => START_1_360_250_END<p><br></p><p>START_2_360_250_END 
  [1] => _360_250_END<p><br></p><p>START_2_360_250 
) 
Array ( [0] => START_2_360_250_END [1] => _360_250 ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( )
Array ( )
Array ( )
```

Comment: *for loop? Poor Regex!*

Answer (score 0):

You're using a greedy match (`.*`) which will always try to match as many characters as possible (resulting in the match spaning two entries).

Just make it a non-greedy match (`.*?`). This will try to match as few characters as possible.

If you'd like to make it even more robust, replace `.` with a more specific class like `\w`, which would match alphanumeric characters as well as `_` (which should be perfect for your case).

Comment: I updated my code it is giving me following array now
Array ( 
  [0] => START_1_360_250_END `[1] => _360_250` ) 
  Array ( 
     [0] => START_2_360_250_END `[1] => _360_250` 
  ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )

Why am I getting the above highlighted string?

Comment: That's what the expression is supposed to match. You didn't specify a following underscore after the first number, so the underscore will be matched inside the brackets/capture group. If you don't want the leading underscore, add it outside, i.e. change `'(.*?)_END/'` to `'_(.*?)_END/'`. If you don't need that additional capture group, you can remove it. The greedy/non-greedy match will work just as fine: `'_.*?_END/'`